# OpenCV cv::VideoWriter stops writing without warning

Tags: c++, opencv, video

I have a strange behaviour with OpenCV's VideoWriter:
After some time (~2 to 5min with an 35fps 1080i MJPEG stream, depending on the type of video recorded), OpenCV stops writing in my file, but keeps it open, and don't give me any clue on what's going on (no cv::exception caught, no assertion, no warning message... no nothing). My program keeps running like if everything works fine, and when I close (cleanly) the program and open the video file, it only contains the XXfirst minutes of video...
Here's a tiny chunk of code:

```
            try{
        m_writer1->write(mat1);
        } catch (cv::Exception & e)
        {
            std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
        if (!m_writer1->isOpened())
        {
            std::cout << "writer1 got pissed off" << std::endl;
        }
```

I release my writer cleanly at the end of my program. Any idea what could go wrong? :/

Comment: Is the "XX" same in multiple runs of the code?

Comment: No, it isn't.. For now, to temporary solve the issue, I have been closing the file and reopening another one every 5min. On a 1h run, I get approximately 10-13 files, containing between 4 and 5min of video. That was when I was streaming a relatively dark and homogeneous desktop background retrieved by an acquisition card. When streaming more colorful and heterogeneous data from a moving camera for instance, the video stops after less than 3min, between 1:30min and 3min approx. I suspect it is related to the ability to compress the frame in jpeg..?

Comment: What is the platform? I'm not sure how the writer object handles all the images you're putting into it, but could it be possible that a buffer or heap is overflowing?

Comment: I have the same problem from Python, after a certain period the video writer just stops writing to a file.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't solve the inner problem, but for me it's enough for now:
Switching to the PIM1 MPEG1 codec solved my problem. I even have a small gain in disk space, and the quality is good enough for my needs.

I don't think my initial problem was caused by an overflow. The video was recording at normal speed, so no overflow possible in the writer. valgrind didn't notice any memory problems, I have no leak etc...

Anyway, thanks all